# always @(*) vs. assign

Tags: verilog

I may have used these interchangeably without thinking, and did not have any problems.

```
always @(*)
  output = input ? a : b
```

or

```
assign output = input ? a : b
```

For a more nested case, the *always* block with *if/else* statements would be more readable, but other than that would there be the case when I should prefer one over another?

Comment: These are equivalent, thus I would prefer the second one as a shorter and cleaner one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`always @(*)` is certainly more readable, especially when writing to more than one output signal with a common set of conditions.

But `@*` can have time 0 simulation problems. If, because of macros or generate statements, the signals in the sensitivity list do not change at time 0 and resolve to constants, you are left with an uninitialized output.

SystemVerilog solved this by creating the `always_comb` block which always executes at least once at time 0.